# Sequent calculus and natural deduction derivation

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

> Given the formula $\exists x(\exists yA(y) \rightarrow A(x))$ of classical logic. Provide a sequent calculus derivation and a natural deduction derivation of the formula.

I started to do something like this for the natural deduction, but then I got stuck:
$$\dfrac{\dfrac{[\exists y\; A(y)] \quad, \quad A(t)}{A(t)}}{\dfrac{[\exists y\; A(y)] \rightarrow A(t)}{\exists x\;\big(\exists y\;A(y) \rightarrow A(x)\big)}}$$

I don't know how the natural derivation will continue, and I also I don't know how to sequent calculus derivation will look like. Sorry for the poor typesetting, but I don't see any easy way to write derivations in MathExchange, and I cannot follow any other method than tree style derivation. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{A(y) \vdash A(y)}{\exists x A(x), A(y) \vdash A(y), A(x)}}{\dfrac{A(y) \vdash \exists y A(y) \to A(y), A(x)}{A(y) \vdash \exists x \big( \exists y A(y) \to A(x) \big), A(x)}}$$

I don't understand how from $\exists x(\exists y A(y) \rightarrow A(x))$ you have obtained $\exists y A(y) \rightarrow A(y)$. Clearly, you have removed $\exists$, but why the $x$ is changed to $y$? Also when you have gone from the second line to third line $\exists y A(y) \rightarrow A(y)$ has been transformed to $\exists x A(x)$, you clearly have done $(\rightarrow r)$, but why is $y$ changed to $x$? And at the end, how did you get rid of $\exists x A(x)$ and $A(x) on the other side completely?

Comment: For your EDIT : you are reding it bottom-up; thus the rule is $\exists$-r and the term $t$ used can be arbitrary : I've chosen $y$. 2nd to 3rd line : you are right, it's a typo; must be $\exists y$ both time.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Okay, not it makes sense :) Thanks for the correction. And regarding the natural deduction part, I spent some time on it, and even tried to make a tree like view of it, but I just couldn't follow it like that, I don't at all see what's going on. Can you someone show me the tree like natural deduction derivation? If it is easier for you, even an image of a handwritten natural deduction derivation is okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Natural Deduction*

It seems to me that we have to "complicate" a little bit the derivation, in order to avoid the "invalid" : $\exists y A(y) \to A(x)$.

1) $\exists y A(y)$ --- premise

2) $A(x)$ --- assumed from 1) for $\exists$-elim

3) $\exists x A(x)$ --- from 2) by $\exists$-intro, followed by $\exists$-elim with 1) and 2)

> 4) $\vdash \exists y A(y) \to \exists x A(x)$ --- from 1) and 3) by $\to$-intro.

Now we can use $\vdash \exists y A(y) \to \exists x A(x)$ in the second part of the derivation :

5) $\exists y A(y)$ --- assumed [a]

6) $\exists x A(x)$ --- from 4) and 5) by $\to$-elim

7) $A(x)$ --- assumed [b] for $\exists$-elim

8) $\exists y A(y) \to A(x)$ --- from 5) and 7) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a]

9) $\exists x (\exists y A(y) \to A(x))$ --- from 8) by $\exists$-intro

> 10) $\vdash \exists x (\exists y A(y) \to A(x))$ --- from 6) and 7)-9) by $\exists$-elim, discharging [b].

---

*Sequent Calculus*

For the *sequent calculus* rules, see :

- Gaisi Takeuti, [Proof Theory](https://books.google.it/books?id=Idl6K-W69NYC&pg=PA11) (2nd ed - 1987)

The  deceptively "simple" derivation :

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{A(x) \vdash A(x)}{\exists y \ A(y) \vdash A(x)}}{\dfrac{\vdash \exists y \ A(y) \rightarrow A(x)}{\vdash \exists x \ \big(\exists y \ A(y) \rightarrow A(x) \big)}}$$

is **wrong**, because in te second line we are violating the *proviso* of the $\exists$-l rule : the *eigenvariable* $x$ must not occur free in the lower sequent.

It seems to me that the way to fix it is the following :

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{A(y) \vdash A(y)}{\exists y A(y), A(y) \vdash A(y), A(x)}}{\dfrac{A(y) \vdash \exists y A(y) \to A(y), A(x)}{A(y) \vdash \exists x \big( \exists y A(y) \to A(x) \big), A(x)}}$$

First we need $\text{Weakining}$ on both sides, followed by $\to\text{-r}$ and $\exists\text{-r}$.

Now, we apply $\exists\text{-l}$, with the proviso satisfied, followed by $\to\text{-r}$ and $\exists\text{-r}$ again; finally, we need $\text{Contraction}$ :

$$\dfrac{\dfrac{\exists y A(y) \vdash \exists x \big( \exists y A(y) \to A(x) \big), A(x)}{\vdash \exists x \big( \exists y A(y) \to A(x) \big), \exists y A(y) \to A(x)}}{\dfrac{\vdash \exists x \big( \exists y A(y) \to A(x) \big), \exists x \big( \exists y A(y) \to A(x) \big)}{\vdash \exists x \big( \exists y A(y) \to A(x) \big)}}$$

Comment: I thought that the sequent calculus derivation would be pretty straightforward like Graham Kemp that has provided. Meaning we do the $(\exists l)$ rule, and we continue reaching $A(t)\mid^t_x \vdash A(t)\mid^t_x$. I thought that things would get pretty complicated for the natural deduction rule. But, seems like I was wrong. xD

Comment: @portal - the formula is *valid* and the calculus is *complete*; thus, the formula **must** be *provable*.

Comment: Firstly, I really didn't understand the natural deduction derivation, I cannot follow it, unless it is in a tree structure. Second, in the sequent calculus derivation, you said below in Graham Kemp's answer, that we cannot do something like this $\exists y\;A(y)\to A(t)\big)\mid^t_x$, but in the third line (I always start from below), you have $\vdash \exists x \big( \exists y A(y) \to A(x) \big), \exists y A(y) \to A(x)$, where the $A(x)$ at the end appear free. Can you show me how the natural deduction derivation will look like in a tree? I tried to convert ti somehow but couldn't manage.

Comment: I also wrote an edit with a few more questions.

Comment: @portal - I've suggested a derivation that seems right to me, but of course I'm wrong. Regarding the "double" formula, we have that $∃x(∃yA(y)→A(x))$ is *valid* while $∃yA(y)→A(x)$ is not. Thus, we cannot have a correct derivation ending with $\vdash ∃yA(y)→A(x)$. The semantics for sequent calculus "reads" $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ as a conjunction on the LHS and a disjunction on the RHS: Thus $⊢∃x(∃yA(y)→A(x)),∃yA(y)→A(x)$ is $⊢∃x(∃yA(y)→A(x)) \lor (∃yA(y)→A(x))$ and this is not invalid.

Comment: Regarding the natural deduction derivation, Shouldn't the step (1) and (2), be something like $\dfrac{\exists y A(y) \quad A(y)}{A(y)}$? And between steps (8) and (9), when you do $∃$, shouldn't we have $∃yA(y)→A(t)$?

Comment: @portal - the $\exists$-elim rule of natural ded has the proviso : $y$ not free in the conclusion $A(y)$. Thus, form $A(y) \vdash A(y)$ (that's right) we cannot conclude by $\exists$-elim with $\exists y A(y) \vdash A(y)$.

Comment: I don't think step (10) is allowed. If assumption [a] is discharged by (8), then it can't be used for (6), needed by (10).  On the other hand, if the assumption [a] is *duplicated* and discharged by (8), then after (6) and (10) it would remain undischarged and the proof would be incomplete.  (Also steps (1) to (4) seem to be a lot of effort used to prove the rather obvious identity `A ⊢ A`.)

Answer (score 0):

Something is fishy here: how is a function supposed to exhibit $A(x)$ with a “known” $x$ from merely $\exists y A(y)$, where $y$ is “forgotten”?  This seems very counter-*intuitive*.  Since the problem description says “classical logic”, I reckon *there is no intuitionistic/constructive proof of this theorem.*  Any attempt that doesn’t involve a *classical* axiom (law of excluded middle, double negation elimination, or equivalent) is bound to fail.

Here's my solution in sequent notation.  It starts off with the law of excluded middle (XM):

$$\dfrac{
\dfrac{
}{
\vdash \exists z A(z) \lor \lnot \exists w A(w)
}\mathrm{XM} \quad
\dfrac{
}{
\exists z A(z) \vdash \cdots
}(1) \quad
\dfrac{
}{
\lnot \exists w A(w) \vdash \cdots
}(2)
}{
\vdash \exists x (\exists y A(y) \to A(x))
}\mathrm{E}_\lor$$

To keep the width of the proof sensible, I split the proof into separate parts (1) and (2), each responsible for handling one of the two possible cases that result from XM.  To avoid confusion, I use distinct letters for different bound variables, but keep in mind that $\exists z A(z)$ and $\exists w A(w)$ are *exactly the same thing*.

Case (1), where $\exists z A(z)$ holds:

$$
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
}{
\exists z A(z) \vdash \exists u A(u)
}\mathrm{Id}
\quad
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
}{
A(u) \vdash A(u)
}\mathrm{Id}
}{
A(u), \exists y A(y) \vdash A(u)
}\mathrm{Wk}
}{
A(u) \vdash \exists y A(y) \to A(u)
}\mathrm{I}_\to
}{
A(u) \vdash \exists x (\exists y A(y) \to A(x))
}\mathrm{I}_\exists
}{
\exists z A(z) \vdash \exists x (\exists y A(y) \to A(x))
}\mathrm{E}_\exists
$$

Case (2), where $\exists w A(w)$ does not hold:

$$
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
}{
\lnot \exists w A(w) \vdash \lnot \exists v A(v)
}\mathrm{Id}
}{
\lnot \exists w A(w) \vdash \exists v A(v) \to \bot
}\mathrm{E}_\lnot
\quad
\dfrac{
}{
\exists y A(y) \vdash \exists v A(v)
}\mathrm{Id}
}{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\dfrac{
\lnot \exists w A(w), \exists y A(y) \vdash \bot
}{
\lnot \exists w A(w), \exists y A(y) \vdash A(x)
}\mathrm{E}_\bot
}{
\lnot \exists w A(w) \vdash \exists y A(y) \to A(x)
}\mathrm{I}_\to
}{
\lnot \exists w A(w) \vdash \exists x (\exists y A(y) \to A(x))
}\mathrm{I}_\exists
}\mathrm{E}_\to
$$

And just to *prove* that this derivation is not completely crazy, here's it is again, written as a Haskell program that correctly type checks:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
module Foo where
import Data.Void (Void, absurd)

data Exists a where
  Exists :: a x -> Exists a

data Theorem a where
  Theorem :: (Exists a -> a x) -> Theorem a

excludedMiddle :: Either (p -> Void) p
excludedMiddle = error "you'll just have to trust me!"

theorem :: Theorem a
theorem =
  case excludedMiddle of
    Left notExists -> Theorem (\ exists -> absurd (notExists exists))
    Right (Exists evidence) -> Theorem (\ _ -> evidence)
```